# Pixelate Texture

Tags: texturing, texture-coordinates, shader-nodes

I know how I can pixelate a texture by pixelating the texture coordinate input that goes into the texture, but is there a way to take an texture output and **than** pixelate it? I try to create a node that takes an image input an a (pixelated) coordinate input and than combines them into a pixelated image output. Sort of like a Image texture node but with a color imput... if you know what I mean?